# The term 'New-AzureRmUserAssignedIdentity' is not recognized as the name

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-module, azure-managed-identity, azure-rm

I'm trying to create user assigned identity, the documentation says that 6.13 should include this function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.managedserviceidentity/new-azurermuserassignedidentity?view=azurermps-6.13.0

I uninstalled old versions of Azure RM and installed the latest:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-Module AzureRM -ListAvailable | Select-Object -Property Name,Version,Path

Name    Version Path
----    ------- ----
AzureRM 6.13.1  C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\6.13.1\AzureRM.psd1
```

But when I try to use it I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\zakima> New-AzureRmUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName PSRG -Name ID1
New-AzureRmUserAssignedIdentity : The term 'New-AzureRmUserAssignedIdentity' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmUserAssignedIdentity -ResourceGroupName PSRG -Name ID1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AzureRmUserAssignedIdentity:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Am I missing some config setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `New-AzureRmUserAssignedIdentity` Cmdlet resides in the `AzureRM.ManagedServiceIdentity` module. This module in turn can be found in the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.ManagedServiceIdentity/1.0.5-preview) and can be installed via:

```
Install-Module -Name "AzureRM.ManagedServiceIdentity" -AllowPrerelease
```

Note that the `AllowPrerelease` flag for `Install-Module` might not be available for your installed `PowerShellGet` version, so you might need to update it before the above would work:

```
Install-Module "PowerShellGet" –Repository "PSGallery" –Force
```

Comment: For me, this worked: `Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity -AllowClobber`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that UserAssignedIdentity is still in preview and apparently is not included in AzureRM package.

The following steps made it work for me:

1. Move to Az package (note - you need uninstall AzureRM first!). It still doesn't include New-AzUserAssignedIdentity.
2. Install Az.ManagedServiceIdentity directly by running this command:

   Install-Module -Name Az.ManagedServiceIdentity
3. Enjoy!

Comment: This is a wrong response, you don't have to move to Az if you are using the older modules. AzureRM has this as well, you can install it via: install-module AzureRm.ManagedServiceIdentity -Allowprerelease

Comment: You're right. That's why I marked another answer as correct. I still provided what worked for me =) This is still a solution to original question.